# How to handle events of dynamically added checkbox on windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am able to add checkbox dynamically on windows form and add data value to its text property. On click of any checkbox I have run a procedure which will make certain other checkbox disabled.

I am not able to find eventhandler for it.

Comment: Please post the code of your dynamically added checkbox.

Comment: I did it more similar to code written by Kyle in answer. Not able to post the code in reply here.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this

```
        CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
        check.Checked = true;
        check.AccessibleName = checkName;
        check.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(340, 40);
        check.CheckedChanged +=new EventHandler(check_CheckedChanged);

        this.Controls.Add(check);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  private void custom_event_handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       ....
  }
```

and then you add checbox like this:

```
 CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
 cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(custom_event_hahndler);
```

Answer (score 1):

if the name of the dynamically added checkbox is c, the answer is as below:

```
c.CheckedChanged += c_CheckedChanged;
```

and c_CheckedChanged is as below:

```
 private void c_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
       {
          ((CheckBox)(this.Controls.Find("c1", false))[0]).Enabled = false;
       }
    }
```

which c1 is the name of the checkbox you want to disable.

Answer (score 0):

Add event handler when you create a checkbox programmatically. And its handler you can do your code logic.

```
CheckBox dynamicCheckBox = new CheckBox();
dynamicCheckBox.CheckedChanged +=new EventHandler(dynamicCheckBox_CheckedChanged);

private void dynamicCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your code
}
```