# C# WinForm how to link a command to a dynamically made checkbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, dynamic

I am currently making a flash drive lock (it hides/unhides folders) in C# Winform.

I've already ready made it the C# Console, so i have most of the commands needed. I have a dir command getting the paths to the all the folders

```
public static dynamic getFolder()
{
    Dictionary<dynamic, List<dynamic>> dictionary = new Dictionary<dynamic, List<dynamic>>();

    int selector = 1;
    bool isHidden;
    foreach (string folderPath in Directory.GetDirectories(Form2.driveLetter))
    {
        List<dynamic> data = new List<dynamic>();
        string folderName = folderPath.Substring(3);
        if (folderName == "#") { continue; }
        if (folderName == "System Volume Information") { continue; }
        isHidden = Status(folderPath);

        data.Add(folderPath.Substring(3, folderPath.Length - 3));
        data.Add(isHidden);
        data.Add(folderPath);

        dictionary.Add(selector, data);
        selector++;
    }

    dictionary.Add(selector++, Vault());
    return dictionary;
}
then I have the Dictionary piped into a different method that gets the names of the folder(and hidden state) then turns them into checked boxes; if the folder is hidden, then the box is checked, and if it isn't, then its unhidden (I will in time make this part more efficient)
```

then I have the Dictionary piped into a different method that gets the names of the folder (and hidden state) then turns them into checked boxes; if the folder is hidden, then the box is checked, and if it isn't, then its unhidden (I will in time make this part more efficient)

```
private void CreateBox(Dictionary<dynamic, List<dynamic>> dictionary)
{
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    CheckBox box;
    for (int x = 1; x < dictionary.Count(); x++)
    {
        List<dynamic> folder = dictionary[x];
        box = new CheckBox();
        box.Text = folder[0];
        box.AutoSize = true;
        box.Checked = folder[1];

        if (y == 180)
        {
            box.Location = new Point(370, 39 + z);
            z += 20;
        }
        else
        {
            box.Location = new Point(198, 39 + y);
            y += 20;
        }
        this.Controls.Add(box);
        CheckBoxes.Add(box);
    }
}
```

[image: image #1]

[image: image #2]

How do I link a SetAttributes command to the check box, so when the box is checked, it hides the respective folder and when the box is unchecked, it unhides the folder

Comment: Please don't link to external sites.

Comment: Is your question just asking how to attach an event handler to a dynamically created control?

Comment: That sounds right, I'm trying to link a command to when a specific box is un/checked. so when the box next to the music tag is unchecked, it fires the unhide command at E:\Music, and if checked again, it will fire the hide command at E:\Music

Comment: I have some understanding on how to do it when the checked box is set there, but I don't know how to do it when it is dynamically made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to hook the event when you're creating your checkBoxes.

```
private void CreateBox(Dictionary<dynamic, List<dynamic>> dictionary)
{
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    CheckBox box;
    for (int x = 1; x < dictionary.Count(); x++)
    {
        List<dynamic> folder = dictionary[x];
        box = new CheckBox();
        box.CheckedChanged += box_CheckedChanged; // here
        box.Text = folder[0];
        box.AutoSize = true;
        box.Checked = folder[1];
        this.Controls.Add(box);
    }
}

private void box_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // some code here.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to call a method once a box is checked or not is to do an event handler, specifically a mouse click.

It looks like you are using Visual Studio to do your winform so I recommend letting Visual Studio handle the creation of the event handler.

1. If you go to the check box's properties and click the little lighting button on the top, it will take you to a list of all events that you can attach to the box.
2. Just find the mouse click event and write a name of the event.
3. In the method itself, check the status of the box (if it is checked or not)
4. Call the method you want based on the status

Here is a Microsoft's documentation on winform's event handling: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dacysss4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the check boxs aren't actually on the base form, they are created through a method. Is there a way to link an event to the box that is made in the method? i know what you are saying, having it update via mouse click and it does work, but is there a way to have it update through the box being un/checked?

Comment: yeah, found that you can create and add event handlers to objects !http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035148/how-to-handle-events-of-dynamically-added-checkbox-on-windows-form