# Enable/Disable specific checkbox in a specific Panel when a checkbox is checked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, panel

I'm coding a C# Forms application.
I have two different Panels on my Form and I'm creating dynamic Checkboxes on both of my Panels. What I wanna do is: if I check a specific Checkbox on panel1 I want to disable/enable a specific checkbox on panel2.

```
foreach (Control checkbox_panel1 in checkBoxPanel1.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control checkbox_panel2 in checkBoxPanel2.Controls)
    {
        if (checkbox_panel1 is CheckBox)
        {
            CheckBox cb_p1 = (CheckBox)checkbox_panel1;
            CheckBox cb_p2 = (CheckBox)checkbox_panel2;

            if (cb_p1.Checked)
            {
                cb_p2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                cb_p2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Code is not doing what I want. It's disabling and enabling the checkboxes in one click. And it's disabling all of the Checkboxes in Panel2 I just want one specific Checkbox to be disabled.

Comment: You are looping thru all the controls in panel and disabling or enabling all the check boxes. Do you have the logic to identify which specific check box to enable or disable?

Comment: You should be using checedChanged event of checkbox. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035148/how-to-handle-events-of-dynamically-added-checkbox-on-windows-form

Comment: I would say you can use the checked event of checkbox1 to disable the checkbox2, but how do you know what checkbox in panel2 to disable if what checkbox in panel1 is checked?

Comment: I am using the checkedChanged Event. My Form is connected to a DB and gets the Values of my DB and creates checkboxes with Values as Names. My first Checkbox is called Car for example. And if i click this checkbox i want to disable the Checkbox Bcylist on my panel2.

Comment: "I'm creating dynamic Checkboxes on both of my Panels. "  Are you creating the "paired" CheckBoxes at the SAME TIME?...if not, you need to be able to "link" them together.  How is that information that the items are related represented in your DataBase?

Comment: Well not really at the same time. First I create the Checkbox named "car" and make it appear on my panel1. After that I'm creating the Checkbox named "Bcylist" and make it appear on panel2. Now I want to make the Checkbox named "Bcylist" unselectable if i click the "Car" Checkbox. The "Items" are in diffrent rows/columns but in the same Table in my DB.

Comment: That still doesn't help.  Is there anything in the DataBase that connects "Car" to "Bcylist", other than just your KNOWLEDGE that they should be connected?  For instance, "Car" might have some kind of unique ID value, and the entry for "Bcylist" might have a field that contains the unique ID for "Car".  Then you can store the CheckBoxes as you create them in a `Dictionary<String, CheckBox>` thus allowing you to "lookup" the corresponding CheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if(cb_p1.name == "your checkbox name")
    {
        if (cb_p1.Checked)
            {
                cb_p2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                cb_p2.Enabled = true;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [.Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name?view=netcore-3.1) property of your CheckBoxes as you create them:

```
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.Name = "Car"; // make sure you set the NAME property!
cb1.Text = "Car";
panel1.Controls.Add(cb1);

CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox();
cb2.Name = "Bcylist"; // make sure you set the NAME property!
cb2.Text = "Bicyclist";
panel2.Controls.Add(cb2);
```

Obviously your code is going to be different since you're reading values from a DataBase.  The key point above is that we set the `.Name` property of the CheckBoxes.

Then, after you've created them, you want to link "Car" to "Bcylist":

```
LinkCheckBoxes("Car", "Bcylist");
```

Using this helper method:

```
private void LinkCheckBoxes(string cbName1, string cbName2)
{
    var ctl1 = this.Controls.Find(cbName1, true).FirstOrDefault();
    var ctl2 = this.Controls.Find(cbName2, true).FirstOrDefault();
    if (ctl1 != null && ctl1 is CheckBox && ctl2 != null && ctl2 is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)ctl1;
        CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox)ctl2;
        cb1.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => {
            cb2.Enabled = !cb1.Checked;
        };
    }
}
```

Now when you check "Car", "Bcylist" will become disabled.  When you uncheck "Car", "Bcylist" will enable again.

If the information about the "linking" was in the DataBase itself then you could automate this process instead of hard-coding "Car" and "Bcylist" into the `LinkCheckBoxes()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario: Two checkboxes controlling another three checkboxes. checkbox1 selected all dependent checkboxes will be selected. if any one of the dependent checkboxes is unchecked the main checkbox will be unchecked and reassigned to another one.

Note: Replace all the Function and component names as per your requirement. Also, add the events to the components

```
private async void FormName_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  checkbox1.checked = true;
  DataSetEnableDisableSettings(true);
}

private void checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
            DataSetEnableDisableSettings(false);
        }
    }

private void checkbox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkbox2.Checked)
        {
            DataSetEnableDisableSettings(true);
        }
    }

private void dependentCheckbox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterButtonCheck();
    }

private void dependentCheckbox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterButtonCheck();
    }

private void dependentCheckbox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MasterButtonCheck();
    }

private void DataSetEnableDisableSettings(bool value)
    {
        checkbox1.Checked = value;
        checkbox2.Checked = value;
        checkbox3.Checked = value;
    }

private void MasterButtonCheck()
    {
        bool dependentCheckbox1State = dependentCheckbox1.Checked;
        bool dependentCheckbox2State = dependentCheckbox2.Checked;
        bool dependentCheckbox3State = dependentCheckbox3.Checked;
        if (dependentCheckbox1.Checked && dependentCheckbox2.Checked && dependentCheckbox3.Checked)
        {
            Checkbox1.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Checkbox2.Checked = true;
            dependentCheckbox1.Checked = dependentCheckbox1State;
            dependentCheckbox2.Checked = dependentCheckbox2State;
            dependentCheckbox3.Checked = dependentCheckbox3State;
        }
    }
```